Finding a real symmetric matrix $\Delta A$ such that the approx eigenpair for A is the exact eigenpair for A+$\Delta A$
Let $ x ∈ R^n$ be an approximate eigenvector of a real symmetric matrix A. (
$∥x∥^2 = 1$)Show that there exists a real symmetric matrix $\Delta A$ such that
$(A + \Delta A)x = xλ, ∥\Delta A ∥^2 ≤ ∥Ax− xλ∥^2$.
where $λ=x^⊤Ax$.

I have tried,$r=Ax−λx,ΔA=rx^T+xr^T$
,but the second condition can't be satisfied.

I suppose that the $2$-norm (i.e., Euclidean norm) for vectors and the induced $2$-norm (a.k.a. spectral norm, which is the largest singular value of a matrix) for matrices are being used. Let $r=Ax-\lambda x$ and $\Delta A=-(rx^T+xr^T)$. Then
\begin{align}
r^Tx&=x^Tr=x^T(Ax-\lambda x)=x^TAx-\lambda=0,\\
(A+\Delta A)x&=Ax-(rx^T+xr^T)x=Ax-r=\lambda x,\\
\|\Delta A\|^2&=\|rx^T+xr^T\|^2=\|r\|^2\|x\|^2=\|r\|^2=\|Ax-\lambda x\|^2.
\end{align}

Sorry,why the 2-norm of  $rx^T+xr^T $equals $∥r∥⋅∥x∥$ ?

@Mizuki Because $r\perp x$.
